# What is the purpose of the typeTok argument to the CIL's stelem instruction?

Tags: arrays, cil

The CIL `stelem` instruction (III.4.26 in [ECMA 335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf) [pdf]) is specified as

```
Format      Assembly Format     Description
A4 <T>      stelem typeTok      Replace array element at index with the
                                value on the stack

Stack Transition:
…, array, index, value,  ->  …
```

I don't understand what the purpose of the *typeTok* argument is.

### Original spec

The following are all the mentions of *typeTok* in the spec:

- In the description:

  > The type of value must be *array-element-compatible-with typeTok* in the instruction.
- In the "Correctness" section:

  > *typeTok*  shall be a valid `typedef`, `typeref`, or `typespec` metadata token.
- In the "Verifiability" section:

  > - the tracked type of *array* is `T[]`, for some `T`;
  > - the tracked type of *value* is *array-element-compatible-with typeTok*;
  > - *typeTok*  is *array-element-compatible-with* `T`

So the *typeTok* is not used for anything; it merely has to be provided. In other words, the only requirement I see is that a *typeTok* that fulfills the conditions has to *exist*.

### Modified spec

However requiring the mere existence of such a *typeTok* is equivalent<sup>1</sup> to changing the above spec sections to

- In the description:

  > The type of value must be *array-element-compatible-with* the element type of *array*
- In the "Correctness" section, remove the above part.
- In the "Verifiability" section:

  > - the tracked type of *array* is `T[]`, for some `T`;
  > - the tracked type of *value* is *array-element-compatible-with* `T`

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> If *value* is *a-e-c-with* the element type of *array*, then because of the reflexivity of the *a-e-c-with* relation, either the type of *value* or the array's element type can be chosen as a *typeTok* that fulfills the requirements of the "Original spec". Conversely, if a *typeTok* with the given requirements exists, then the transitivity of the *a-e-c-with* relation immediately yield the requirements of the "Modified spec".</sup>

---

So what am I missing? Why is the *typeTok* argument there (and thus why do the `stelem.<type>` instructions except for `stelem.ref` even exist)?

Comment: Very hard to answer, this IL instruction is only ever used in generic code.  The jitter and the verifier readily use the token in their code to perform checks and decide what code to generate.  Whether it is there just to give them an easier time or whether it is truly necessary to deal with array covariance is something I can't bring home, they are the hard parts of .NET.  Chapter I.8.7.1 is a headache.  Curiosity or a real problem?

Comment: Curiosity, mainly. Trying to dig into IL a bit, and this caught my attention when going through the spec.

Comment: Usually the shorthand versions exist for the primitive types so you don't have to use a typetoken. This causes the it to be 4 less bytes. Shorter methods in general have a higher chance to be inlined.

Comment: @MichaelB I'm aware of that, but if the type parameter of the long version served no purpose, than the shorthand versions would be equally useless (and the long version could be just as short).

Comment: Technically, you can as the CLR demonstrate use ldelema for each of the array indices and then use stind or stobj. Its way more bloated. They exists because the CLR verifier also is checking intent. The sequence, `ldloc.0`,`ldc.i4.3`,`ldc.i4.8` `stelem.ref` is clearly wrong, as you need to box the int before it goes into the slot.

I think the intent was for non-primitives structs and generics. But perhaps because non-primitives aren't used as much in arrays (maybe they are used more in a generic context) the sequence was never as optimized?

Answer (score 2):

`Stelem TypeToken` exists to support ValueTypes that are non-primitives. The only other option would be to box these structs if this opcode didn't exist.

There are a family of stelem.* elements. For the primitives [i,i1,i2,i4,i8,r4,r8,and ref]

the primitive ones tell it to expect a particular sized element on the stack and it should be read, ref says that there is an object reference. Now what about a `struct` that are not primitives. You might say just use one of those primitives of the same size. After all, it's what it does for an array of `Enum`.  Consider `DateTimeOffSet`. It's 12 bytes and thus you can't use one of the existing primitives. It would be bad to have to box to store an array of these elements.

The other opcode that exists is `stelem.any` and it's there for the generic code. This simply is a shortcode in case where `TypeToken` might be a reference to a `class` type. You could always use `stelem.any` but it is wasteful to use 4 extra bytes if the typetoken is handled by the primitives.

`CIL opcodes` that need type information always take them as operands, even when it should be obvious based on other elements on the stack. This is probably just to make life easier on the CLR team. (consider `box` needs an opcode). This might also be there to help emitters avoid making mistakes.
e.g.

```
ldc.i4.8
box typetoken(long)
//whoops we clearly need to conv.i8 before we can box this as a long.
```

Why do the shorthand versions exist (e.g. `Stelem.i4` is just `stelem typetoken(int32)`? They exist to be 4 less bytes. Shorter methods have a better chance to be inlined. It use to be that if a method was more than 32 bytes of IL it would not be inlined.

Edit:
I'm wrong. It seems C# usually grabs the address of struct address elements and stores them. Technically you can use stelem TypeToken (as that is what is emitted in the generic case), but it seems that the VS team does not.

```
var dynmethod = new DynamicMethod("test", typeof(void), new[] { typeof(DateTimeOffset[]), typeof(DateTimeOffset) });
        var gen = dynmethod.GetILGenerator();
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Stelem, typeof(DateTimeOffset));
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        var d=dynmethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<DateTimeOffset[], DateTimeOffset>)) as Action<DateTimeOffset[],DateTimeOffset>;
```

This sequence works as expected, so I don't know why they chose the other route.